# JQuery Slider and ZF1 producing much shorter images than expected

Tags: php, jquery, css, zend-framework

I am trying to use a jquery content slider (i.e. bxslider, url: http://bxslider.com/) along with zend framework v1.12. With the following code I can slideshow the images and their titles, but the expected image size is much short only 285x165 while the sought after image dimension as per my css code should be at least  590x341. I cannot figure where the problem is? I have tried various settings without any luck.

```
    <?php
  $this->script()->appendFile($this->APP_STATIC_URL . '/templates/default/js/jquery.bxslider.js');
?>
<?php
  if ($this->numArticles > 0):
?>

 <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
 <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 341px;">
    <ul class="bxslider" style="width: 3215%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(-1180px, 0px, 0px);">

    <?php
      foreach ($this->articles as $article):
?>
    <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 590px;" class="bx-clone">
    <div class="slider-image">
    <a href="/health/foods-cause-cancer" title="Foods and Cancer: We Expose Suspect Science">
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="<?php
          echo $article->getCover('original');
?>" width="648" height="375" alt="" title="Foods and Cancer: We Expose Suspect Science"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-content">
        <h2 class="slider-title">
            <a href="/health/foods-cause-cancer" title="Foods and Cancer: We Expose Suspect Science"><?php
          echo $article->title;
?></a></h2>
    </div>
    </li>
    <?php
      endforeach;
?>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bx-controls bx-has-controls-direction bx-has-pager">
    <div class="bx-controls-direction">
        <a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a>
        <a class="bx-next" href="">Next</a>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>

       <?php
      $this->script()->captureStartOnce('bx-wrapper');
?>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport .bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,

    });
});
<?php
      $this->script()->captureEndOnce('bx-wrapper');
?>
<?php
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: Tidying up the code-snippet may improve the readability.

Comment: I formatted the code somewhat.

Comment: Testing a bit here: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/g2bhbh05/ I notice you hard code your `IMG` tag as so: `<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" width="648" height="375" alt="" title="Foods and Cancer: We Expose Suspect Science">`. What is the size of the source images?

Comment: the source image size is not fixed but it is larger than 400x400 in all cases.

Comment: Since I cannot see it rendered, nor can I see your CSS, I really can't determine why the size is not what you want it to be.